# View android network traffic via wireshark

Tags: android, networking, packet

I'm trying to view the protocol on an app I'm using to see how it works but I can't find any traffic (except netbios traffic) coming from my Android phone (HTC Aria).

I don't have any way of getting any hardware for this and i'm using the phone on my router's wifi and the PC is directly connected to my switch.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to use something like Charles SSL...point your phone at some kind of Proxy server that captures traffic.
If you connect the phone and your computer w/ Wireshark to the same network via a router (not a switch which won't show you shared traffic), you can use Wireshark to monitor all the traffic to you phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are attempting to use WireShark in this scenario, but what you should do is use a packet sniffer like [Shark for Root](https://market.android.com/details?id=lv.n3o.shark) *on your android phone*.

Comment: This requires the device to be rooted. My phone is incredibly hard to root.. :/